# PayPal sandbox IPN validation always return INVALID

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I googled this question and tried all suggestions but nothing works.

I tried this code: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/ but it don't work. Just copy-pasted it and deleted old magick_quotes routunes.

I tried this code: http://samples.geekality.net/view-source.php?file=ipn/ipn_handler.class.php and it also do not work.

In all cases I tried to do following:

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate&' . file_get_contents('php://input');
```

To ensure I sent to IPN **exactly** what it sent to me. In addition I used the debug proxy (Fiddler) and saved what IPN sent to me and what I sent to IPN. The requests bodies are byte-to-byte identical except my request is prefixed by the `cmd=_notify-validate&` string.

Yes, I checked I use proper sandbox URL. Here are entire requests bodies:

What IPN sent to me: (I just replaced personal data to XXX)

```
POST http://localhost.loc/en/payment/success/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost.loc
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 921
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

mc_gross=1.00&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&payer_id=5XNKM66NSDKC4&tax=0.00&payment_date=05%3A34%3A11+Jun+01%2C+2015+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=utf-8&first_name=XXX&mc_fee=0.33&notify_version=3.8&custom=topup%3A262262%3A1%3A1433162020&payer_status=verified&business=XXX&quantity=1&payer_email=XXX&verify_sign=AG58dBsn5g2z8O8NEjotbuJGP14PAIpZ4k26VL8IyhaDPkcDRj002Keq&memo=hmgvjgjhgfjhfggjhfjtfgjh&txn_id=4CN141026K278934Y&payment_type=instant&last_name=XXX&receiver_email=XXX&payment_fee=0.33&receiver_id=DCMXPXGX4QX6J&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Account+top+up&mc_currency=USD&item_number=Account+262262+top+up&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=topup%3A262262%3A1%3A1433162020&payment_gross=1.00&shipping=0.00&auth=ANSTBwT3znll-gJQZO2cLoV5QJFW9v8W.FqyWxffdtI0L-9mfsoe2xRL44M86Sn2XtYGtcqG4Fjjel1kdYZyxpQ
```

What I sent to IPN:

```
POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 942
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=1.00&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&payer_id=5XNKM66NSDKC4&tax=0.00&payment_date=05%3A34%3A11+Jun+01%2C+2015+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=utf-8&first_name=XXX&mc_fee=0.33&notify_version=3.8&custom=topup%3A262262%3A1%3A1433162020&payer_status=verified&business=XXX&quantity=1&payer_email=XXX&verify_sign=AG58dBsn5g2z8O8NEjotbuJGP14PAIpZ4k26VL8IyhaDPkcDRj002Keq&memo=hmgvjgjhgfjhfggjhfjtfgjh&txn_id=4CN141026K278934Y&payment_type=instant&last_name=XXX&receiver_email=XXX&payment_fee=0.33&receiver_id=DCMXPXGX4QX6J&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Account+top+up&mc_currency=USD&item_number=Account+262262+top+up&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=topup%3A262262%3A1%3A1433162020&payment_gross=1.00&shipping=0.00&auth=ANSTBwT3znll-gJQZO2cLoV5QJFW9v8W.FqyWxffdtI0L-9mfsoe2xRL44M86Sn2XtYGtcqG4Fjjel1kdYZyxpQ
```

Can anyone help me what I do wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You should migrate your edit to an answer on your own question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AARRRRGH!!!!!!!! I have only dirty words to PayPal!!!!!!! The problem was in... (drumroll... tadam!) in the `charset` field! No, its value must be the same as IPN sent it to you, but... in UPPERCASE! IPN sends it in lowercase! So you MUST modify IPN data to verify it successfully regardless manual tells us to return data back "as-is". PayPal bug?

So my final working code is: (using HTTP_Request2)

```
protected function verifyPostData() {
    $this->request->setBody('cmd=_notify-validate&' . str_replace('=utf-8', '=UTF-8', file_get_contents('php://input')));
    $response = $this->request->send();
    if ($response->getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Transaction data verification request failed with code {$response->getStatus()}");
    }
    $content = trim($response->getBody());
    return ($content == 'VERIFIED');
}
```

How I did it: I sent the PDT request for this transaction and obtained transaction data. Then I made field to field comparison of PDT and IPN data. PDT have no some IPN fields such as `auth`, `verify_sign` and `test_ipn`. But all other fields seems must be the same. And the only difference was in the characters case of the `charset` field. Then I tried to verify modified data and unexpectedly it become successful!

Answer (score 0):

This is a recent PayPal bug, when the customer completes a payment and clicks on "Click here to return.." instead of waiting a few seconds, the parameters passed to the PDT script on your site are sent in lowercase.

This also messes up things like a case-sensitive or encoded cm/custom parameter.

Apparently PayPal are aware of it.